# What preposition I should use with the word "application"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Which one of the following three sentences is correct? I am not sure what preposition I should use with the word "application". Thanks.

1. My job is to facilitate the application of this new technology **in** solving complex problems.
2. My job is to facilitate the application of this new technology **to** solve complex problems.
3. My job is to facilitate the application of this new technology **in** complex problems.

Comment: Start over. Just call yourself a troubleshooter and it'll mean as much or as little.

Comment: If you have to choose anything like one of those, try rather 'My job is to facilitate the application of this new technology to complex problems'. In any case, how is this not more about personal choice and style in Writing, than EL&U?